# Path traversal in POST request?

Tags: windows, linux, file-upload, directory-traversal

Does it make sense to try path traversal on the filename value during a file upload request? Should I encode special characters in the POST request?

For example

```
POST 
[...]

----boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hello.pdf"; filename="..\..\..\..\license.rtf"
```

Comment: yes it makes absolute sense

Answer (score 1):

I would also try single quotes in the file name, you never know you'll find a SQL injection if the filename is inserted into a DB without sufficient sanitization.

Notes from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition):

> The string following filename should always be put into quotes; but,
> for compatibility reasons, many browsers try to parse unquoted names
> that contain spaces.

You might also try to spoof the MIME type (Content-Type) in case the underlying application is relying on it rather than check the file extension (although this is unlikely).

Perhaps try a very large file name, like 255+ characters and see what happens.

PS: In this example `name` should be the HTML form field name, I doubt it would be called hello.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on how your program handles filenames. However, path traversal isn't done with encoding, you actually have to check which directory your file is getting written into.